# Use Drupal 6 APIs in custom webpage?

Tags: php, api, drupal

I want to have a non-Drupal website create a user account in my Drupal installation when a form is submitted. Is there a way to include (and otherwise initiate) the drupal APIs in a php script that is not inside a drupal module? I have tried including some include files as the "unknown function" errors keep coming up, but it has turned into a cat-and-mouse game.

Thank you for your help,
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, use [`services.module`](http://drupal.org/project/services). It provides APIs for Drupal.

Or:

```
<?php

chdir('/path/to/drupal/');
require_once('includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

**edit:** Per the comments, for command-line usage, you have to spoof `$_SERVER` stuff that Drupal relies on (particularly the domain name):

```
<?php

// set some server variables so Drupal doesn't freak out
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/script.php';
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = '/script.php';
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'example.com';
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';

// act as the first user
global $user;
$user->uid = 1;

// change to the Drupal directory
chdir('/path/to/drupal');

// Drupal bootstrap throws some errors when run via command line
//  so we tone down error reporting temporarily
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

// run the initial Drupal bootstrap process
require_once('includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

// restore error reporting to its normal setting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: That seems like it could work but now the output of the php script is a webpage saying the drupal site is down. However browsing to the drupal site in the browser shows that it is working. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to use the command line? If so, you'll need to spoof some `$_SERVER` stuff that Drupal relies on. http://wiki.ceejayoz.com/w/Using_the_Drupal_API_from_the_command_line